# Change of Young double slit pattern after a reflection

Tags: experimental-physics, reflection, double-slit-experiment

I made a Young double slit experiment  on sunlight that showed  clearly the pattern of maximum and minima  demonstrating the wave aspect of light.Anyway, if, beyond the double slit the light is reflected by a  front surface aluminized mirror or a grating in zero order before reaching the screen (in my case a CCD), the Young pattern appears to be changed : it seems duplicated,with two maximum; why?

Comment: A photograph would do nicely here.

Comment: You should clarify with a sketch of your setup.

Comment: Thanks to all: the report of my experiment is at the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVYmiXTFIT2_tvI9IJsteGAKlMMNEdZe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Mmm. You say sunlight which per Newton prism expt we know to be composed of the full rainbow of colours. The maxima and minima direction angles are wavelength dependant and so you should get a splurge of colour seperation. The diffraction angle goes like  NLambda/D . From blue through red the wavelength (Lambda) doubles and so the angle to first max should be double for red. So you should see a central whitish slightly redish edges with later blue max then red max and in between colours. Yeah, i just checked with Google "double slit for white light" and see images.
Perhaps this explains the ghosting ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very much appreciated.I made sunlight coherent by the use of a 35 nm Halpha filter and a 100 micron pinhole.You can give a look to my experiment at this link:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVYmiXTFIT2_tvI9IJsteGAKlMMNEdZe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm afraid my previous comment wasn't posted, so I repeat it.Thanks for your answer, much appreciated, I used a monocromatic interference filter and a pinhole to make coherent the incoming sunlight.The report of my experiment is at teh link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oVYmiXTFIT2_tvI9IJsteGAKlMMNEdZe/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for kind replies to my question.Regarding the problem carefully, I convinced myself that the anomaly in the Young interference pattern could be due to a return of marginal rays back from the double slit (in glass) to the detector.To verify such assumption I planned to change my setup with a plastic not reflecting double slit end a better quality (at least 1/10 lambda) aluminized mirror. When done, I'll announce the results here.